# How to print characters and integers from a char array

Tags: java

I have string array as `char[] onlyArr={'A','B','C','D','1','2','3','4'};`
How do I get to this?

```
A,1
B,2
C,3
D,4
```

With the syntax `[letter][number]`

Comment: you do not have a string array , but an array of char just to be clear, however, you must also save the numbers ?

Comment: Appologize ...Corrected ..thanks :)

Comment: it is not a string array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should do some research on your own first (and if you have, show evidence). However, here is a solution.

```
int halfLength = onlyArr.length / 2 + (onlyArr.length % 2);
for(int i = 0; i < halfLength; i++){
    System.out.printf("%c,%d%n", onlyArr[i], (int)(onlyArr[i + halfLength] - 48));
}
```

When printing the integer, you have to subtract the ascii value of '0' (48) from the character and then cast the result to an int.

The assignment of `halfLength` could potentially be optimised, but this code will do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming definition is `char[] array={'A','B','C','D','1','2','3','4'};`, now as I understand you want to associate the elements among themselves, now with your example i would do something like this,

```
// Arrays are fixed-length and here we also know the sequence
// Individual judgment is anyway required to establish the right pattern

for (int i = 0; i< array.length/2; i++)
    System.out.println(array[i]+","+array[i+4]);
```

Comment: Good answer. Like i think...

Answer (score 0):

You can start from the left and from the right simultaneously in `onlyArr` and print it accordingly :

```
char[] onlyArr={'A','B','C','D','1','2','3','4'};

int n=onlyArr.length;
int i=0,j=(n)/2;

while(i<n/2)
{
    System.out.println(onlyArr[i]+""+onlyArr[j]);
    i++;j++;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to write the values of an array the syntax it's this:

```
String[] myString = {1, 2, 3}
System.out.println(myString[0]); 
// OUTPUT-> 1. Be careful. Position 0 it is the first in all arrays
System.out.println(myString[1]); // OUTPUT -> 2
// .....
```

To print all the values you should use a foreach loop:

```
for(String temporary_var: onlyArr){
    System.out.println(temporary_var);
}
```

Foreach it is a short form to work with arrays, because you avoid creating counters. It would be the same as this:

```
for(count = 0; count < onlyArr.length; count++){
    System.out.println(onlyArr[count]);
}
```

If you want to write like: 1, A. 2, B. 3, C... you could use a normal-for-loop:

```
for(count = 0; count < onlyArr.length; count++){
    System.out.println(v + ", " + onlyArr[count]);
}
```

Comment: Check the semantics and syntax of the first code snippet. It's not even valid Java.